# how do i loop/repeat/range(whichever you call it) print a text in python?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

what did i do wrong in this piece of code that it will not loop print? please send the correct answer.

```
repr(
"input()means you tell the computer something"
)
range(
"input()means you tell the computer something"
)
```

Comment: i want it to repeat "input() means you tell the computer something"

Comment: why did you dislike? i clearly just asked a question because im new to coding.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're trying to do. Can you try rewording your question? Also showing what the output of your code was, and what output you expected, would help.

Comment: _"i want it to repeat "input() means you tell the computer something""_ This is covered by most basic python tutorials. Stack Overflow is not a replacement for tutorials. Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask], 
and the [question checklist.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953) Welcome to SO.

Comment: i did use the enters but in this website they didnt appear since i copy pasted my code here.

Comment: i expected it to loop/range/repeat (whichever you call it) this sentence: "input() means you tell the computer something"

Comment: they disliked just because im new and i dont know how to loop/repeat/range

Comment: I suggest you take [tour] and check [ask] and [help/on-topic]. This will make your stay on this site much more fruitful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not too sure what do you want to achieve with this piece of code, but there are multiple ways to repeatedly print a string in python. Here are a few ways:

1. Using a while loop (this will run infinitely)

```py
while True:
    print("input()means you tell the computer something")
```

2. Using a for loop (if you want to print it for a definite amount of times)

```py
times = int(input("How many times do I repeat?: "))
for i in range(times):
    print("input()means you tell the computer something")
```

I hope that answers your question

Comment: your answer is absolutely the most useful answer i got